# I am trying to replace text using replacers in email template - PHP

Tags: php

**Hello Community**

I am trying to replace text in email templates using data from database.

This is my code where `%<$receiver>%` works and `%<$sender>%` doesnt.

If you have any knowledge what im doing wrong or hints what i should change i would appreciate it.

```
  public static function getRowValue($type, $receiver, $sender, $job) {

    $model = self::where('type', $type)->where('status', DEFAULT_TRUE)->first();

    if ($model) {

        $subject = $model->subject;

        $page = "admin.templates.email.email";

        $email = $receiver->email;

        $model->content = html_entity_decode($model->content, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8');

        $sender_replaced = ($sender) ? str_replace('%<$sender>%',$sender->name, $model->content) : $model->content;

        $receiver_replaced = ($receiver) ? str_replace('%<$receiver>%',$receiver->name,$sender_replaced) : $sender_replaced;

        $job_replaced = ($job) ? str_replace('%<$job>%',$job->name,$receiver_replaced) : $receiver_replaced;

        $message = $job_replaced;

        $email_data = [];

        $email_data['message'] = $message;

        Helper::send_email($page,$subject,$email,$email_data);

        return $model->message;

    }

    return "";
}
```

If you need additional informations please feel free to ask, hope my example will help someone else who is having hard time solving this issue.

```
<?= $email_data['message'] ?: "NO MESSAGE" ?></span></p>
```

Line how i call data in email template.

Comment: Make sure `$model->content` contents required placeholders.

Comment: Hello, thanks for fast response, here is line how i send to template : <?= $email_data['message'] ?: "NO MESSAGE" ?></span></p> . What you suggest i should do ?

Comment: I don't care how you send. You say that problem in your code is `%<$sender>%` is not replaced by actual value? So __check out__ why - look at your data and make sure that `%<$sender>%` __exists__.

Comment: Ive allready var_dump that information $sender does exist.

Comment: What does the string contain? `var_dump($sender_replaced)`

Comment: Name of sender .

Comment: Sorry, `$model->content`, post the actual content, it has `%<$sender>%` in it?

Comment: Looks like $sender is NULL.

Comment: I would hazard to guess that there is no %<sender>% in the $model->content. Double-check that it's there, and typed properly and in UTF8.  Does job work?

Answer (score 0):

There was nothing wrong with this part of code, ive missed data flow logic in controllers where i was pulling out $sender and it hasnt been accepted by user.

I have to change data flow logic now to make it work.

Thanks all on help.